# How to access Exception information that occurred as part of a Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best approach to handling exceptions thrown in a separate thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293388/what-is-the-best-approach-to-handling-exceptions-thrown-in-a-separate-thread)

When bad things happen, my code throws an Exception, that is later being caught and handled.

If said code runs as part of a thread however, `public void run()` does not `throw Exception`.  How can the executor of the tread know about exception being thrown?

Now:

```
 A a = new A();
 try {
    a.doSomething();
 } catch (Exception e) {
    // do something clever
 }
```

With Threads

```
 Thread t = new Thread (new A());
 t.start(); // run() calls doSomething()
```

**If this threads fails with exception, how can i know about it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an ExecutorService

```
ExecutorService es =
Future<Type> future = ex.submit(new Callable<Type>() {
    public Type call() throws Exception {
        // do something
        return result;
    }
});

// later
try {
    Type result = future.get();
} catch(ExecutionException e) {
    Throwable exceptionThrown = e.getCause();
}
```

if you don't have anything to return you can use the following.

```
Future<Void> future = ex.submit(new Callable<Void>() {
    public Void call() throws SpecificException {
        // do something which might throw SpecificException
        return null;
    }
});
```

Comment: Peter, in this case, should threaded code catch it's exceptions? If not, where should it throw them? At what point, since `run` is not it

Comment: Callable/call() can throw any Exception and return a value.  It is placed in the `Future`. When you try to get the value, a wrapping ExecutionException is thrown.

Comment: In this case, if `run` would `doSomething`, what should `call` do? what what should call return? Should it return `this`?

Comment: If you don't have anything to return, I would `return null;` I have added an example.

Comment: If you haven't used the concurrency libraries much I would suggest you read up on them.  On of the best books for advance Java developers is JCIP http://jcip.net/ Written by the main author of the library.

Answer (score 6):

You can set an uncaught exception handler on the thread via [Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29), which will handle any exceptions that are not handled within your code.

Essentially:

```
t.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
  public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e)() {
    // do whatever
  }
});
```

Also, if you want a handler for all threads, you can call [Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29) which is a static method to provide a handler for threads when there isn't one specifically for it.

Comment: this will be called after unhandled exception, and will happen only after the thread is terminated.

Comment: That is correct, but what do you expect the thread to do when it receives an unhandled exception?

Comment: In this case, when exceptions are caught inside the the thread, should anything extra be done to make sure they are seen from outside (since `run` can't `throw Exception`)

Comment: If you don't want to continue the thread, but make sure its handled externally, you can wrap it in a RuntimeException and rethrow it, ala: `throw new RuntimeException(e)` from within your try/catch. If you do want to continue the thread, it's not really an uncaught exception, and you would do whatever you normally do.

Answer (score 4):

you can catch the exception *in-thread* and then pass it as an event to the creator thread.

Comment: Could you please provide example?